# PHP: How do I can show data in modal box based on clicked button's row id in gridview?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, yii2-basic-app

I've a Yii2-basic application that has view of **index.php** that contain a kartik GridView. There is an action column that contain `view` button that will redirect the page to view of **view.php** if clicked.

[image]

If the **view** button clicked, page will redirect to **view.php** and show data based on id,

For **example** from image above, that table contain two button in **view** column. If the first(top) button clicked, it will show data base on `id` from **id**  column (left side of table), so it will show data that has `id = 1`.
And I've successfully create this action.

But I need to show data in **modal box**. So I use `yii\bootstrap\Modal`. And I've succesfully show the data in **modal box**. For the first clicked, it will popup **modal box** that contain data based on `id`, but for the next click button it will also show the data based on `id` that got from the first clicked button.

For **example** from picture above: 
For the first time I click the button from the second row (`id = 2`) and then popup a **modal box** that contain data that has `id=2`, and then I click the button from the first row(`id = 1`) and it will also popup **modalbox** that contain data that has `id = 2`.

#### Here's my code from index.php:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;

<div class="students-index">
<?=
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-hover'],
    'columns' => [
        [
            'label' => 'id',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return $data->id;
            }
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Name',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return $data->name;
            }
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Birthdate',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return $data->Birthdate;
            }
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Sex',
            'value' => function($data) {
                return $data->Sex;
            }
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'header' => 'View',
            'template' => '{view}',
            'buttons' => [
                'view' => function ($url, $model) {
            $icon = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>';
            return Html::a($icon, $url, [
                        'title' => Yii::t('app', 'View'),
                        'data-toggle' => "modal",
                        'data-target' => "#myModal",
            ]);
        },
            ],
            'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
        if ($action === 'view') {
            $url = Url::toRoute(['/school/students/view', 'id' => $model->faktur_out_id], ['data-method' => 'post',]);
            return $url;
        }
    }
        ]
    ],
]);
?>

</div>

<?php
Modal::begin([
'id' => 'myModal',
]);
 Pjax::begin([
     'id'=>'pjax-modal','timeout'=>false,
     'enablePushState'=>false,
     'enableReplaceState'=>false,
 ]); 

 Pjax::end();

 Modal::end();
?>

<?php
$this->registerJs("
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var href = button.attr('href') 
    $.pjax.reload('#pjax-modal', {
    'url' => href,
    });
"); ?>
```

#### How do I can show the data in modal box based on id?

But actually I didn't understand `$this->registerJs("......")` yet.
Maybe anyone can explain about it in simple language.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->registerJs(" ");` 
is simply a function in the Yii framework that allows you to write the javascript in between the `" "`.

Try this:

```
<?php
Modal::begin([
'id' => 'myModal',
]);
 Pjax::begin([
     'id'=>'myModal','timeout'=>false,
     'enablePushState'=>false,
     'enableReplaceState'=>false,
 ]); 

 Pjax::end();

 Modal::end();
 ?>

<?php
$this->registerJs("
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var href = button.attr('href') 
    $.pjax.reload('#myModal', {
    'url' => href,
    });
"); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge, so if that just like you said. I can guess if my code above is not correct.

Comment: It didn't solve my problem, it's has result as my code has.